# Zoom into a picture based on Mouse Position

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image contained within a picturebox on my WinForm. I want to add a feature that lets the user zoom in to the picture based on where the mouse is when they scroll the mouse wheel. Right now my form looks like this

[image]

The truss is the image I want to add my proposed zoom feature to. I added a mousewheel event that looks like this

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Delta < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zoom Out");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zoom In");
    }
    MessageBox.Show(e.Location.ToString());
}
```

So I have the location of the mouse when the user zooms and whether they are zooming in and out. However, I'm not sure about how to do the math so that it zooms where the mouse is. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stop using the Image property and implement the Paint event instead.  Now you can use Graphics.ScaleTransform() and TranslateTransform().  You also need to make it focusable so you'll actually get the MouseWheel event.  Did you even try this??

Comment: I can declare a class variable called scale that starts at 1f and changes when a user zooms, then call paint by invalidating the picture. Question becomes how to make the transform center on where the mouse is and not on the center of the picture

Comment: In the sidebar you will find many solutions. Note that imo the best way to do the zooming is using a list of zoom factors, like photoshop does. This helps making it both smoth and reversible..